# Bias reduces Accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am programming an application to recognise handwritten digits with the MNIST dataset for school, I added a bias and wanted to write that it improves accuracy but it actually didn't help. After one epoch accuracy without bias was 91.6% and with bias 91.53%. After more epochs there was not much difference. This surprised me a lot, could someone tell me why the bias doesnt help in my network? Maybe the code is wrong but I dont think so.

```
import tensorflow as tf
iN = 28*28
hN = 150
oN = 10
lr = 0.2
epochs = 15

wih = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((iN,hN), stddev=0.1))
who = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((hN,oN), stddev=0.1))

bh = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((1,hN)))
bo = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((1,oN)))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1,28*28])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1,10])

hidden = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x,wih) + bh)
output = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(hidden, who) + bo)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y, output))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)
```

Comment: Your network is correct. The problem with Neural Networks is that due to their nature they make it hard for you to access what worked and what didn't, so I don't think that there is a concrete answer to your question (you could always hypothesize though...). My hypothesis is that a bias term doesn't add that much complexity to the model, in fact many modern architectures omit bias terms altogether. A rule of the thumb: In Machine Learning you can't be sure what will help and what won't before testing them.

Comment: The digit recognition task is normally modeled as a multi-class classification problem rather than a regression problem. I doubt it is appropriate to use the RMSE loss here.

Comment: See https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials and https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn for more information.

Comment: I think a sample size of 1 after 1 epoch is hardly significant. Try running it more times from random initialization and for more epochs.